# Intellij Idea doesn't recognize generated classes if they are not in the same directory

Tags: intellij-idea

So I have an issue with Intellij Idea because it absolutely wants my generated ressources to be in the folder of their package, otherwise it won't work (but it still compiles)

Here are my files, as they should stay

[image: files]

The "package" file view is wrong too

[image: package]

And other files from the same package doesn't recognize their brothers and there's a big red mess, this is my issue

[image: broken]

As said, only Intellij Idea is complaining because when I run maven, it compiles with no errors.

I already tried making Antlr4 generating files in `target/generated-sources/fr/bananasmoothii/scriptcommands/core/antlr4parsing`, but it was messy because Intellij idea was marking the wrong directory as generated source, but after remarking correctly the directories, it worked perfectly.

Afterwards, I though it is better to generate files normally and make Intellij idea understad what it should.

Comment: How do you generate the parser? Do you use the antlr maven plugin? How did your configure the header in your grammar? Have you added the `generatedSourcesDirectory` to the maven compile plugin?

Comment: @Peter everything is here: https://github.com/bananasmoothii/ScriptCommands/blob/master/pom.xml (yes, I use the maven plugin), and for configuring the header I use `@header`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/bananasmoothii/ScriptCommands/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/ScriptsParser.g4). What is `generatedSourcesDirectory` ?

Comment: @Pater also, this is probably nothing related to maven as maven does things perfectly

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov you can found my project [here](https://github.com/bananasmoothii/ScriptCommands/tree/f433fc50050deb114719c6b9b53646c599456941), read `COMPILING.md` to generated the files.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I reported issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255367. Please follow it for updates.

Comment: @y.bedrov thanks but I already created one lol: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255256